# get list of parents id in json object

Tags: jquery, json, recursion

My nested json looks like:

```
var obj ={ "Name": "Main", "Id": "1", "Parent": "0", "children": [{ "Name": "Main1", "Id": "2", "Parent": "1", "children": [ ...
```

obj is tree structure that looks like this:

[image]

How do I parse obj to get the id of any parents of a specified id?

a jquery function for example `function getIdParentsOf('25') { }`

output be example: parents of 25 until 1 is `{20, 18, 10, 1 }`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"to get id of parents of my certain id?"*? Where is `id` 25 in the sample json? how does passing 25 returns results *untill 1* ? where did 1 came from? Your question is totally unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration is just an object with specific properties, including an array of child nodes of the same type. Basically a tree structure

You have updated the question making it clear now the tree is hierarchical. That means you need to walk the tree recursively. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/gdwjmqwh/6/

```
// If the required node is found, return true
// matching nodes added to the result parameter
var findParent = function (parentnode, id, result) {
    if (parentnode.Id == id){
        result.push(parentnode.Parent);
        return true;
    }
    if (parentnode.children) {
        for (var i = 0; i < parentnode.children.length; i++) {
            var node = parentnode.children[i];
            if (parentnode.Parent && findParent(node, id, result)) {
                result.push(parentnode.Parent);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // no matches found - return false
    return false;
}
```

Call like this

```
var result = [];
findParent(obj, "2", result)
console.log(result);
// Displays an array of parent ids
```